# How to do one quick sort procedure for different structures

Tags: c++, qt

For each `QTableView` object I have `QAbstractTableModel` object.

```
//base model class with sorting
class dm : public QAbstractTableModel{
...
    dosort(...);
}

//=================
// model for grid N
class dmN : public dm{
   ...
   //one data row   
   struct mNrow{
    ...
   };
   //data rows: vector with pointers to mNrow structures
   std::vector< mNrow * > mNrows;
   //compare functions for sorting
   char fcomp0(int li,int lj){...}
   char fcomp1(int li,int lj){...}
public:
   //we will call to sort column
   sort(int column,...){
      if (column==0) {dosort(mNrows,fcomp0);}
      else if (column==1) {dosort(mNrows,fcomp1);}
   }
}
// grid N
class dgN : public QTableView{
...
    dmN * dgNm;
}
```

I want to retrieve each row data for `QAbstractTableModel` object from a structure.

So, each row is a structure.
All pointers to rows (structures) are stored in a vector.

It is for easy rows sorting (just compare and swap pointers if needed).
The problem is I want one sort procedure but many different structs to sort.

1. So, I need to pass to sort procedure pointer to a vector and to a compare function.
2. I need to have ability to swap different type pointers inside the vector.

Thanks.

Now, with std::sort it is better, but not so beautiful as I want.

```
//base model class with sorting
class dm : public QAbstractTableModel{
    ...
    int rows; 
    int currow;
    //sort
    virtual void dosort(int column,Qt::SortOrder order){}
    void sort(int column, Qt::SortOrder order=Qt::AscendingOrder){
        if (rows>1) {
            beginResetModel();
            if (currow<0) currow=0;
            dosort(column,order);
            endResetModel();
            emit sorted(currow);
        }
    }
 }

//=================
// model for grid N
class dmN : public dm{
   ...
   //one data row   
   struct mNrow{
        int f_er;
        Qstring * f_name;
    ...
   };
   //data rows: vector with pointers to mNrow structures
   std::vector< mNrow * > mNrows;
public:
    // compare func for column 0
    struct fcmp0{bool operator()(mNrow * li,mNrow * lj){
    return   (QString::localeAwareCompare(*(li->f_name),*(lj->f_name))<0);
    }} f0;

    //compare func for column 1
    struct fcmp1{bool operator()(mNrow * li,mNrow * lj){
    return  ((li->f_er)<(lj->f_er));
    }} f1;

    //do sorting
    void dosort(int column,Qt::SortOrder order){
       //  !!!! this string I can't move to sort and have to copy to each dm
       //save row ptr
       mNrow * lrs=mNrows[currow];

       if (column==0) {std::sort(r.begin(),r.end(),f0);}
       else if (column==1) {std::sort(r.begin(),r.end(),f1);}

       //  !!!! this part I can't move to sort and have to copy to each dm
       if (order!=Qt::AscendingOrder) {
           int lj=(rows-1);
           mNrow * lst;
           for (int li=0;li<=( lj >> 1);li++){
             lst=mNrows[li];
             mNrows[li]=mNrows[lj-li];
             mNrows[lj-li]=lst;
           }
       }
       //goto saved row ptr
       currow=-1;
       int li=0;
       for(std::vector<mNrow *>::iterator it = mNrows.begin(); it != mNrows.end(); ++it) {
           if (*it==lrs) {currow=li;break;}
           li++;
       }
    }
}
// grid N
class dgN : public QTableView{
...
    dmN * dgNm;
}
```

Comment: Do you know about std::sort?

Comment: You should use std::sort unless you have a very good reason not to. A compilation error you cannot explain is not one of those good reasons. Try asking a question about this specific error.

Comment: Don't format comnents, you can't. Edit your question instead.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I'll try and will write to the answer.