# How to store a pointer to compare function for std::sort in array?

Tags: c++, sorting

I need to do sorting in my class like that:

```
typedef bool (*fcomp)(int,int);

class mf : public QAbstractTableModel{Q_OBJECT
public:

  //horisontalHeader struct
  struct hs {
    QString h;//column name
    Qt::AlignmentFlag a;//align
    fcomp s;//compare function for std::sort
  };

  //data 
  hs h[cc]={
  {t("Function"),Qt::AlignCenter,cf},
  {t("Errors"),Qt::AlignCenter,cer}
  };

  bool cf(int li,int lj){return
    (QString::localeAwareCompare(tf->r[li].f_name,tf->r[lj].f_name)<0);}

  bool cer(int li,int lj){return
    ((tf->r[li].f_er)<(tf->r[lj].f_er));}

  void dosort(int column){
       std::sort(
       i.begin(),
       i.begin()+rowCount(),
       h[column].s);
  }
```

How to declare compare functions to store them in array?

The compiler error:

```
cannot convert 'bool (mf::*)(int, int)' to 
'fcomp {aka bool (*)(int, int)}' in initialization
```

Before I've used method from here  [How to do one quick sort procedure for different structures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35885827/how-to-do-one-quick-sort-procedure-for-different-structures) but I don't like it:

```
// compare func for column 0
struct fcmp0{bool operator()(mNrow * li,mNrow * lj){
return   (QString::localeAwareCompare(*(li->f_name),*(lj->f_name))<0);
}} f0;

//compare func for column 1
struct fcmp1{bool operator()(mNrow * li,mNrow * lj){
return  ((li->f_er)<(lj->f_er));
}} f1;

if (column==0) {std::sort(r.begin(),r.end(),f0);}
else if (column==1) {std::sort(r.begin(),r.end(),f1);}
```

Comment: A pointer to a member function is not the same as a pointer to a non-member function. Read about [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) and [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) for alternatives. Or use `static` member functions which can be converted to a pointer to a non-member function.

Comment: Thanks. `Static` works perfect.